# Cannot resolve method 'makeText(Data.DataBaseHandler, java.lang.String, int)'

Tags: android, toast

Please check this, There are two issues first one is this database is not creating and the second one is this toast is giving me this error.

```
 public static final String KEY_ID="id";
public static final String KEY_NAME="Name";
public static final String KEY_IMAGE = "levelone";

public DataBaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + KEY_ID +
            " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_IMAGE + " BLOB" + ")";
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

    Toast.makeText(DataBaseHandler.this,"sadads",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
}
```

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Database is not creating why?

Database created when you first call either `getWritableDatabase()` or `getReadableDatabase()`. Because `DataBaseHandler` just creates helper.

```
DataBaseHandler helper = new DataBaseHandler(context);
helper.getWritableDatabase();
```

> 2. Toast is not showing why?

Toast needs a context to show. You can't use `SqliteOpenHelper` which is `DataBaseHandler` as a context. But you can use context passed within constructor to `getApplicationContext()`.

```
public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "Name";
public static final String KEY_IMAGE = "levelone";
private Context context;

public DataBaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + KEY_ID +
            " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_IMAGE + " BLOB" + ")";
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "sadads", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
}
```

Comment: Thank you database is created, and toast is also working ..